# RSACNG encryption works with service but fails with ui

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a VS solution. i have 5 projects that create 3 executables.
Two of the executables run as services, and one is a windows form executable.
All three are wrapped into an inno installer.
When i install the 3 applications, the two services use the encryption fine, and have absolutely no issue.
When the UI tries to run, it fails on `result = crypto.Decrypt(data, oaepSHA256);`, I get the error:

> "Exception":"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The parameter is incorrect.

I know the parameter can work, because it does work on the two services.

```cs
public static byte[] Decrypt(string keyName, byte[] data)
{
    RSA crypto = GetRSACNGKey(keyName);
    byte[] result = null;
    try
    {
        Logger.Debug(" VHEncryptionRSA.decrypt ");
        RSAEncryptionPadding oaepSHA256 = RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256;
        result = crypto.Decrypt(data, oaepSHA256);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(" VHEncryptionRSA.decrypt fails", ex);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I do not understand why the error occurs with the UI?

All three programs are decrypting the same file. The parameters for `crypto.Decrypt(data, oaepSHA256);` are the same for all three programs.

Comment: Are you using the same machines for working client and server as where you are failing?  What are the differences (version net for example)? Are all using same HTTP or HTTPS? I'm not sure if code is failing the TLS authentication or some place later in code.  A parameter failing could mean you are using the wrong padding mode for the key or a different encryption algorithm for decrypt than was used for encrypt.  You could be trying to decrypt something that was not encrypted.  there could be lots of reasons for failure.

Comment: Just did some testing I was only able to reproduce this error using a byte[] that has the same length as RSA encrypted data but every member was null. Make sure the data you are passing is valid RSA encrypted bytes and verify that the byte[] is fully populated. Edit: I was also able to reproduce the error by setting *any* byte in the array to default.